# C remove node for a linked list when this is empty

Tags: c, linked-list

I am doing functions to manage linked lists in c and I am having trouble with the remove function. this just takes a pointer to a linked list and a value and deletes the first node with that value. The thing is that if I pass an empty list, I get a segmentation fault. Any idea?

```
sll_node *sll_remove(sll_node *list, int search_value)
{
    sll_node* head = list;
    sll_node* delete = list->next;


    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return list;
    }

    if(head != NULL && head->value == search_value)
    {
        list = head->next;
        free(head);
        return list;
    }

    while(delete)
    {
        if(search_value == delete->value)
        {
            head->next = delete->next;
            free(delete);
            return list;
        }
        head = head->next;
        delete = delete->next;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: yes, `list->next` crashes if `list` is null. You need a check  before this statement.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you! As it is in c, I can´t move the check before the statement, so I set delete to NULL and then gave the value. Thanks again Serge

Comment: you could use the ternary operator and say something this: `sll_node* delete = (list == NULL) ? NULL : list->next;`

Comment: "As it is in c, I can´t move the check before the statement" what keeps you from using C99 or higher??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `list` is null before dereferencing it

```
 sll_node *sll_remove(sll_node *list, int search_value)
    {
    if(!list){
          return list;
    }
        sll_node* head = list;
        sll_node* delete = list->next;


        if(!head)
        {
            return list;
        }

        if(head && head->value == search_value)
        {
            list = head->next;
            free(head);
            return list;
        }

        while(delete)
        {
            if(search_value == delete->value)
            {
                head->next = delete->next;
                free(delete);
                return list;
            }
            head = head->next;
            delete = delete->next;
        }

        return list;
    }
```